# How to simulate SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly in .net core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

i need to make parallel request in .net core.

In MVC is easy to do that with

```
SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly
```

but i suppose we can not use in .net core app so How to simulate `System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly` in .net core

Answer (score 1):

i think i figure it.

We can not use `SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly` but there is a new methor for make parallel requesting. Normaly session lock request queue and we have to wait request is finish and process to next request form queue.

But if we make Session load async with `Session.LoadAsync()` method than it's make requests parallel.

**How We Do That**

```
internal static async Task<int> GetSessionInt(this ISession session, string key)
        {
            await session.LoadAsync();
            return session.GetInt32(key).Value;
        }
```

Than call method from action

if action is async

```
int id = await HttpContext.Session.GetSessionInt("id");
```

if action is not async

```
int id = HttpContext.Session.GetSessionInt("id").Result;
```